# vtk python rendering issue on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, render, vtk

I am able to compile all the codes on python + vtk + ubuntu

why programs are compiled well but does not render anything ??

```
import vtk

# create a rendering window and renderer
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

# create a renderwindowinteractor
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# create source
source = vtk.vtkDiskSource()
source.SetInnerRadius(1)
source.SetOuterRadius(2)
source.SetRadialResolution(100)
source.SetCircumferentialResolution(100)
source.Update()

# mapper
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputData(source.GetOutput())

# actor
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

# assign actor to the renderer
ren.AddActor(actor)

# enable user interface interactor
iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

This code compiled well but does not show any output.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/GeometricObjects/Display/Disk this

Comment: How have you installed vtk? Which version? In one of the related questions, a user had a similar problem with Slicer, can you try that as well?

Comment: Is it possible to render the vtk GUI in HTML or web-browser page?